# Javascript surround code in function?

Tags: javascript

Is there actually a difference between these two snippets? are there any benefits? they're both embedded in my html document via the script tags

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var masthead = document.getElementById("js-masthead"),
        pageWidth = masthead.offsetWidth,
        viewportHeight = window.innerHeight,
        fluidPadding = (viewportHeight / pageWidth) * 100;

    masthead.style.paddingTop = fluidPadding + "%";
};
</script>
```

And

```
<script>
var masthead       = document.getElementById("js-masthead");
var pageWidth      = masthead.offsetWidth;
var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
var fluidPadding   = (viewportHeight/pageWidth) * 100;

masthead.style.paddingTop = fluidPadding + "%";
</script>
```

Would you be able to suggest any better alternatives or better ways to code my javascript?

Comment: The `onload` function will be executed once the DOM is ready...and the other will be executed whenever the `script` tags are processed. They're different, but can have the same effect depending on where the bottom snippet is placed.

Comment: @tymeJV I barely use inline javascript tag, so does the second one introduce golbal variables in the code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would there be much of a speed difference if for example the script tag is place directly under the div with the id "js-masthead" in comparison to onload?

Comment: @grape_mao -- Yes, but also, it depends on where that script is on the page and when it is evaluated.

Comment: @davethebrave -- Typically scripts should be placed at the bottom of the page so the DOM can load up first. Performance wise, shouldn't be much, but you can use www.jsperf.com and find out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there actually a difference between these two snippets?

Yes, there are several differences.

The first snippet registers a function to be called when the window load event is dispatched.
This means that if you were to load the first script dynamically after the window loads, the code would never be executed.

The second snippet is executed after the script tag is parsed. This means that depending where the script is placed in the HTML, you may or may not have the `#js-masthead` element to work with.

The first snippet wraps your code in a function, so every variable is local to that function. The second snippet pollutes the global scope with variables you'll probably never use again. *Hint: IIFE can help here.*

> Would there be much of a speed difference if for example the script tag is place directly under the div with the id "js-masthead" in comparison to onload?

Yes, but not how you would expect. Placing a `script` tag with code that interacts with the DOM in the body will negatively affect performance. Modern browsers optimize page load as much as possible and do several things at once (pipeline-ing) to show your content as soon as possible. If you read or write DOM properties before the document is ready, you will force the browser to have a consistent state between the data structures used in your page,  throwing away any possibility of pipeline-ing. This effect is mitigated if the scripts are at the end of the `body` tag.

**TL;DR: do your DOM interaction in the onload handler if you care about performance.**

Comment: Thank you the great reply! If I'm not mistaken, is it good practice to surround code in a function to prevent pollution of the global scope? also would it be recommended to rewrite the code using the IIFE pattern to prevent the pollution of the global environment? I guess I kind of attempted to keep the variables local by using the onload function

Comment: Yes, you will find that most libraries use IIFE to prevent global namespace pollution. You don't need to use IIFE though, the code you posted seems better fit in the onload handler.